# How to use jquery-modal dialog box in this situation?

Tags: jquery

I am already using `tablesorter.js` which is dependent on `jquery.js` file. Now, I am trying to use the modal dialog which turns out to be dependent on `jquery-1.9.1.js`. Since 2 jqueries can't be on the same template how can I get both tablesorter.js and jquery dialog to work together? If I remove jquery.js and only include jquery-1.9.1.js, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tablesorter'
```

Error.

And if I remove jquery-1.9.1.js and include only jquery.js then I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'dialog'
```

I am using Javascript and css like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: ._0 .. why do you want to include the same library twice?

Comment: Haven't you read the question properly? I have stated that in my question.

Comment: both tablesorting and dialog will run with single library

Comment: if you already have included the latest version of jQuery, why do you want to include jquery-1.9.1?

Comment: You need to run one of the jQuerys in no conflict mode.

Comment: can you show us the js code how you call the dialog and how you call the tablesorter on specific elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Contains two jquery libraries.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Choose one. Try this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

If an error is occured again then try to post additional code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove following line,

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

and it should looks like,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />  
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```