# Error in jquery Dialog when used with jquery tablesorter pager JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dialog

I have a Admin screen in Area = "PrivateCEQRApplication". I am using Jquery table sorter (http://tablesorter.com/docs/) and jquery dialog (https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default) in that page. I am using MVC4 and razor.

My view is

```
@model CEQRApplication.Areas.PrivateCEQRApplication.Models.CEQRUser

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AdminPage";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LogoutLayout.cshtml";
}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui.css")" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-latest.js")" type="text/javascript">   </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.mod.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (event) {

    $(".tablesorter")
            .tablesorter({
                widthFixed: true,
                cssChildRow: "expand-child",
                widgets: ["zebra"],
                headers: { 0: { sorter: false } }
                , onRenderHeader: function () {
                    this.wrapInner("<span></span>");
                }
                , debug: false
            })
            .tablesorterPager({
                positionFixed: false,
                container: $("#pager")
            })
            .bind('pagerChange', function () {
                $('.expand-child td').hide();
            });      


    $('.buttonsAddUser').click(function (event) {

        $("#editResult").dialog({
            title: 'Add User',
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 650,
            show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
                $(this).load('@Url.Action("AddUser", "Admin")');
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        });

        $("#editResult").dialog('open');

        return false;
    });    

 });
</script>
```

my button and div for rendering dialog

```
<td style="padding-left:30px;">
    <div class="buttonsAddUser">
        <img src="@Href("~/Content/themes/base/Images/add-users.png")" style="height: 2.0em; width: 3.0em; vertical-align:middle; display:inline-block; cursor:pointer;" id="AddRow" alt="Add User" title="Add User" />
         Add New User
     </div>
</td>
<div id="editResult" title="Edit User">
</div>
```

Now the issue is when i use these script only on the page and remove table sorter

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui.css")" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

dialog works

and when i use these script only on the page and remove dialog

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-latest.js")" type="text/javascript">   </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.mod.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

sorter works

but if i put the j-query script for both sorter and dialog dialog throws the error

**
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'**

I am using tablesorter.js which is dependent on jquery.js file. Modal dialog is also dependent on jquery-1.9.1.js. Since 2 jqueries can't be on the same template how can I get both tablesorter.js and jquery dialog to work together? is there any way i can resolve this issue I will really appreciate the help.

Also, I am not very clear on the concept of bundling. So if i want to bundle the scripts shown above how will i do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 versions of jQuery loaded (`1.9.1` and `latest`).

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-latest.js")" type="text/javascript">   </script>
```

jQuery UI is loaded after the first one, and is attached to that instance of jQuery. When you load the second jQuery, you're essentially throwing out the first one along with any plugins attached to it.

Pick one version of jQuery that works with both jQuery UI and the sorter, and make sure the jQuery script the first of the scripts you load, and both the dialog and sorter should work. For example...

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-latest.js")" type="text/javascript">   </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.mod.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**--- Update ---**

Since it appears that you need different versions of jQuery... one for jQuery UI (1.9.1) and one for the sorter (1.4.x, in jquery-latest.js), you're going to have to do something like this...

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-latest.js")" type="text/javascript">   </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.mod.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $oldJQuery = $.noConflict();
    // $ is now 1.9.1, $oldJQuery is the first jQuery that was loaded ("latest")
</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Anywhere where you need to access the table sorter plugin, you need to use `$oldJQuery`, otherwise just use `$`...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (event) {

    $oldJQuery(".tablesorter")
            .tablesorter({
                widthFixed: true,
                cssChildRow: "expand-child",
                widgets: ["zebra"],
                headers: { 0: { sorter: false } }
                , onRenderHeader: function () {
                    this.wrapInner("<span></span>");
                }
                , debug: false
            })
            .tablesorterPager({
                positionFixed: false,
                container: $("#pager")
            })
            .bind('pagerChange', function () {
                $('.expand-child td').hide();
            });      


    $('.buttonsAddUser').click(function (event) {

        $("#editResult").dialog({
            title: 'Add User',
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 650,
            show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
                $(this).load('@Url.Action("AddUser", "Admin")');
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        });

        $("#editResult").dialog('open');

        return false;
    });    

});
</script>
```

Comment: well I am not sure what is going on with the scripts but if i remove jq latest I get an error in jq.tablesorter.mod.js - 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined. if i remove 1.9.1.js i get an error in jquery-ui.js 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Can you open up your copies of jquery-latest and jquery-ui and see what versions they are (hopefully there are comments at the top)? Need to make sure they're all compatible.

Comment: i c. well jq-laters is v1.4.2 and jq-ui is v1.10.3. I hope this is the problem. I will search of jq-ui version v1.4.2 and try running teh code

Comment: There is no matching version of latest and ui. I was search online and  found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183824/how-to-use-jquery-modal-dialog-box-in-this-situation how does Static url work..

Comment: jQuery UI requires jQuery 1.6+. It sounds to me like the sorter is incompatible with later versions of jQuery. Perhaps you can find a copy of jQuery 1.6 or 1.7 and see if it's able to work with both jQUI and the sorter. You can try to run different versions of jQuery on the same page but that gets a bit messy.

Comment: Updated answer with how to use 2 different versions of jQuery on the same page.